# Codename One: use Fontello with CSS

Tags: codenameone

*Note for the readers: this question is not about standard CSS, but it's related exclusively to the CSS support of Codename One.*

I'm not satisfied of the Material Font Icons included in Codename One.
I want to replace almost all these lines:

```
FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_XXX, "ColorWhite", 4)
```

with something different taken from Fontello.
In the past I read how to do that using the CSS support included in Codename One, but at the moment I'm not finding what I read. I only found this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-icon-fonts-such-as-fontello.html, but it doesn't explain how to use the CSS.

So my question is the correct coding to use Fontello icons inside a Codename One app using CSS *(is there any tutorial?)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just declare the font as explained here https://github.com/shannah/cn1-css/wiki/Fonts

Roughly something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fontello";
    src: url(res/Fontello.ttf);
}
```

Then you can apply the font to any UIID you wish to use such as:

```
MyIcon {
    font-family: "Fontello";
}
```

Comment: Today I discovered that this method is fine only for a single "Fontello.ttf" font. To use more ttf files downloaded from Fontello in the same project, it's necessary to rename them using a cross-platform free tool like https://fontforge.org/, as explained in https://superuser.com/a/120607.

Comment: Yes since they have the same font name. A better approach is to create one large file which is just what fontello does